# How to conclude the best parameter configuration of an optimisation algorithm?

Tags: optimization, parameterization

Suppose that one is given an algorithm for solving a specific optimisation problem. This algorithm has various parameters (say, e.g., $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$) that have to be fine-tuned to the algorithm achieve better results.

$p_1$ can be set to be equal to 1, 2 or 3. $p_2$ can be set to be equal to 1 or 2. And $p_3$ can be set to be equal to 1, 2, 3, 4. The idea is to found the best parameter configuration (e.g., $p_1=1$, $p_2=2$ and $p_3=4$) that is able to improve the efficacy and effectiveness of the algorithm.

Thus, it was randomly chosen a set of optimisation functions, from all the most used benchmark function, and the algorithm was tested with all the combinations of different parameters values. Besides that, for each combination, ten tests were executed and the execution time and the algorithm output value is saved (lower is better -- minimisation problem). In total, my data set of test results have $(3×2×4)×10=240$ samples of two elements (execution time and algorithm output).

In order to conclude that, on average, for any optimisation problem the best parameter configuration is, e.g., $p_1=1$, $p_2=2$ and $p_3=4$, what kind of analysis should I conduct? An ANOVA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the **objective function** of the optimization problem. Two approaches to hyperparameter optimization are:

1. **Grid search**: for each parameter that needs to be tuned, assign a range of values and estimate the model for each combination of values within the specified ranges. Then evaluate your performance criterion on each calibrated model. In other words, you exhaustively run through all parameter values and come up with a large number of fitted models from which you can cherry-pick the most optimal set of parameters by graphing the effect on model performance of increasing/decreasing the parameters against one another
2. **Bayesian optimization**: Instead of exhaustively running through a grid of models, you once again specify a range of values for each hyperparameter, but let a Bayesian toolbox like hyperopt in python intelligently iterate through a select few combinations of the parameters. This obviously can be much more efficient. It evaluates the objective function, by taking it to be random because it is unknown, placing a prior distribution on it, and uses the evaluations to update the prior to form a posterior distribution, which in turn is used to construct an acquisition function that directs the next query point. A less expensive way to define the prior/posterior distribution of the objective function is to use Parzen Tree Estimators which constructs two distributions for 'high' and 'low' points, and then finds the location that maximizes the expected improvement.

Could also consider,

3. **Heuristics and annealing**: Study the impact of slowly amping up certain parameters vice versa by feeling out what could be a right value for each parameter, and select a model that finds an optimal level of your performance criterion. More relevant and manageable for a uni-parameter problem.
4. **Analytical derivation**: If the problem is a construct of linear equations, you can back out optimums for each hyperparameter using math.